# How TO: Typescript nested typing A<B<GENERIC>>

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to have this kind of typing in typescript ?

```
interface Worker<T> {
    renderChunk: (projectUrl: string, from: number, to: number) => Promise<T>;
}

interface WorkerPool<W<U>> {
    addWorker(worker: W, address: number): void;

    getIdleWorker(): W | null;
}
```

But I also want some type of restriction that checks that `W` should be an implementation of `Worker`, let's say you have for example an implementation of Worker as follow:

```
class RenderWorker implements Worker<string[]> {
    renderChunk: (projectUrl: string, from: number, to: number) => Promise<string[]> {
         return Promise.resolve(['Foo'])
    }
}
```

The below implementation should be acceptable by typescript:

```
class RenderWorkerPool implements WorkerPool<RenderWorker> {}
```

however this one should not be acceptable as `string` is not an implementation of `Worker`

```
class RenderWorkerPool implements WorkerPool<string> {}
```

Comment: If you want `WorkerPool` to only accept `Worker` implementations, then why don't you just use directly the `Worker` interface? Like changing all `W` to `Worker`.

Comment: How so? bcs I've tried some different syntaxes but none seems to work for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using [constrained generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), you can ensure that `W` extends `Worker`.

```
interface WorkerPool<W extends AaWorker<any>> {
    addWorker(worker: W, address: number): void;

    getIdleWorker(): W | null;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-XnnbN5hai17bb6dg6AkA)

Because of the nested generic, if you want to reason about the type of the worker, you'll need to specify that as well:

```
interface WorkerPool<U, W extends AaWorker<U>> {
    addWorker(worker: W, address: number): void;

    getIdleWorker(): W | null;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJwOoHsoGtoA8AKgHzIDeAsAFDJ3JQQgAm0AwgBYCuIuAXMgAUAByhYAVhARgAqlAA2AgM5gooAOYAaZDDEBbASC56ARtG1gsh42agBKZAF4yABX3AlEYiQDcNAL40NKCQsIgo2HjQLlhY8gQy2hjIEAAekCxKaJg4+FAJJGRUtPRwzMyReYIA7rnQAhjaZcyMSkrWptB2AgBuWMDMftQ09MjqEGAAkszyEJXQgt3IyQA+yEby8kOBw9QI8nBtyABKTKxQ81DIwHrCs3pMYFnolwQqaiDqANoAukUj9EYLHY3F4IjEkmkckUyHeGm0uiwBnWNnMyEsHVsSzcSI8Xjhn1+-xKozojDAXCgIGQOL0eIAdK04j0IIIvgByABisXZPzsALoOx2NDSwhwYGQ+0OWVOwIudSgMTiAH0sLhrrd7o8spclfECd8ftpZedLsTRs1LosKAwJpSQD5kDtRuMpjM5grreRbRSqSjNo6hUFqKLxZKDkcTdBdbF5Mr4MB5Bq7hAHuAdQq9W9VPDYTnPmQKALkJbPQ5veT7YHi67prMreWffb-VsnQEgA)

But, as [Bernardo Duarte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7395911/bernardo-duarte) points out in the comments, you might not need generics for Worker at all. Instead, just take any conforming Worker implementation with the right generic type:

```
interface WorkerPool<U> {
    addWorker(worker: AaWorker<U>, address: number): void;

    getIdleWorker(): AaWorker<U> | null;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJwOoHsoGtoA8AKgHzIDeAsAFDJ3JQQgAm0AwgBYCuIuAXMgAUAByhYAVhARgAqlAA2AgM5gooAOYAaZDDEBbASC56ARtG1gsh42agBKZAF4yABX3AlEYiQDcNAL40NKCQsIgo2HjQLlhY8gQyZFS09HDMzJH4UIIA7jhZAuiZhInaacyMSkrWptB2AgBuWMDMftQ09MjqEGAAkszyEMXZ9WiY+SVkAD7IRvLybYHt1AjycFXIAEpMrFDDyMB6woN6TGBKY8MEKmog6gDaALpJHfSMLOzcvCJiktJyimQNw02l0WAMsxs5mQlhqtlGbnBHi8wLuTxeKU6dEYYC4UBAyERemRADpKnEGhBBPcAOQAMViNMedledCWSxoEAAHsIcGBkKt1hdth89hMoDE4gB9LC4A5HE5nC7DSXxVEPZ4UVnIcrDQQOcgMHp4kA+ZBLTrdPoDIbi-UUI24-GQ+Zm9lBajc3lQfmCjYi3Yq2LyKXwYDyeXHCCncDK8Wq66qDRkLWYnXpPUGx0mt3aq39QaZh04k0uhbmgJAA)

(I've changed `Worker` to `AaWorker` above, just so there's no naming conflict between your Worker and the Web Worker built-in objects.)

Comment: Thanks you Jeff for you detailed answer! It's much clearer 

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
interface WorkerPool<W extends Worker<unknown>> {
  addWorker(worker: W, address: number): void;
  getIdleWorker(): W | null;
}
```

`W` is constrained by `Worker<unknown>`. So `W` is inferred to be a `Worker`, and the generic `T` of that worker is also inferred as part of that.

```
class RenderWorkerPoolA implements WorkerPool<RenderWorker> {} // fine
class RenderWorkerPoolB implements WorkerPool<string> {} // Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'Worker<unknown>'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBJBvAsAKB0-SAlsAC4QBOAZgsgOoD25A1hQDwAqAfBngX+RGAATCgGEAFgFdgTAFxIAFDHL0AVhHgkAquQA28qCXLEA5gBoklFWHnBJYAEYULJerftPyASiQBebgAK1oRQEBycANy8+AC+ONFEpBTUiEgMzBQB9PS6rLRIEAAeZMJQaYws5KzSTMD0AO7AnNxY2Hx8IEJC6ZUK9RUU8rQWnUICUFDujhRe8gBu9IRCUW3t+CYQJACSQroQPRQKs2lIAD5Idrq6K3xxuKv48LogE0gASoIi5AfkRGAwe0gpDKP1YhmMwBMAG0ALotBL8T5iKQyJQqdSaHT6JDg0wWKz0GwXDzOJCuKaeY5BQkhMK4yGw+EPNYEAQkSTkYBIalgWkAOnGOTmEAUUIA5AAxbJimFeBEEO63eLMp4vMofYQUH5ZHJoQj-QGCEgggbkHW5DVfH4tRUEVWvS1a03mgBCfwBECBxvKGTN2Vy9JMNqQypwdxwQA)

Comment: Thank you Alex for you answer and the explanation accompanied 